# Certain GIT quotients for elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

The base field $k$ is algebraically closed.

Let $C$ be a smooth projective variety and $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $C$ (as an algebraic variety). As is well known, up to isomorphism there is only one smooth projective curve $C'$ whose function field is $k(C)^G$. I will denote the quotient of $C$ by $G$ as follows: $C^G:=C'$.

remark: I am denoting the quotient variety by $C^G$ instead of the usual $C/G$ to not creat confustion in what follows.

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve, and $G$ be a finite subgroup of $E$. $G$ can be seen as a group of automorphisms of $E$ (as an algebraic variety, not as a group): $G \times E \rightarrow E$ is $(g,p) \mapsto g+p$. The quotient group $E/G$ clearly is the space of orbits for this action. Does $E/G$ with the quotient topology has a natural structure as a smooth projective variety making it isomorphic to its quotient $E^G$?

Comment: First off, you should try and figure out what the semistable locus is in this case. Secondly, what smooth projective variety are you hoping $E/G$ may be? This is another avenue to approach this problem you presented.

Comment: @K02 I can clarify what I mean a by the quotient. In general, let $C$ be any smooth projective curve, and $G$ a finite group of automorphisms of $C$. The invariant field $k(C)^G$ is again a function field of transcendence degree one, and hance there is only one smooth projective curve $C'$ with function field isomorphic to this invariant field. $C/G:=C'$

Comment: @jg1896 - If you are given an embedding $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2:=S$ and an open affine cover $U_i:=Spec(A_i)$ of $C$ with an induced action $G \times U_i \rightarrow U_i$, you may define $U_i/G:= Spec(A_i^G)$ as the spectrum of the invariant ring. Then you may glue these quotients $U_i/G$ to a global quotient $C/G$.

Comment: ..when a finite group $G$  acts on a quasi projective variety $X$ over a field $k$, there is always such an open affine invariant cover. Hence you may always construct $X/G$.